# C# Inheritance Type Casting error

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, casting

I'm a bit new to inheritance in C#. I have two classes `Velocity.cs` and `Position.cs` that inherit from the base class `Vector.cs`. I'm trying to create a method called `subtract()` inside `Vector.cs` that will be accessible from `Velocity.cs` and `Position.cs`.

Here is the code for subtract.

```
     public Vector subtract(Vector v) {
        double nx = this.x - v.x;
        double ny = this.y - v.y;
        double mag = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double ang = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        return new Vector(mag, ang);
    }
```

The code defining the `Velocity.cs` class is below.

```
class Velocity : Vector{

    public Velocity(Position p1, Position p2, double vpref) : base(p1, p2) {
        normalize();
        scale(vpref);
    }

    public Velocity(double vmax) : base(new Random().NextDouble()*vmax, new Random().NextDouble()*2*Math.PI) {

    }

    public void change(Velocity v) {
        x = v.x;
        y = v.y;
        magnitude = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        angle = Math.Atan2(y, x);
    }

}
```

}

When I try to call the function subtract outside, something like this:

```
        Velocity v1 = new Velocity(5);
        Velocity v2 = new Velocity(7);
        Velocity result = v1.subtract(v2);
```

I get an error saying *Cannot explicitly convert between 'Velocity' and 'Vector' Did you forget a cast?*

So I tried `Velocity result = (Velocity)v1.subtract(v2);` however that results in the following error: *An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred*

How can I rewrite this function to make this work? Do I really have to make three versions of the function with return types `Vector` `Velocity` and `Position`? If so what is the point of inheritance? I could just put them in their associated class.

*Note: I'm aware that the velocity class is kinda small and may seem pointless at the time, I'll be adding more to it later, I'm in the middle of a project.*

Comment: Side note, don't do `new Random()..., new Random()... `.  Instead, create a static instance of the Random class and use that instead. Otherwise you'll get the same number quite often.

Comment: Also, your subtract method returns a `Vector`. You are trying to assign it to a variable of type `Velocity`. While it is true that a `Velocity` is a `Vector`, a `Vector` is not necessarily a `Velocity` (it can be a `Position`). You can always do `Vector result = v1.subtract(v2);` but you'll only have access to the common fields defined in `Vector` which may or may not be enough depending on your use case. Another side note: per C# naming conventions, method names should start with a capital letter, ie `Change(...)` and `Subtract(...)`.

Comment: I see you liked the first answerer's approach. BTW double-check mine... I believe that it matches what you want in a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see what's happening here. So your subtract function returns a Vector object but C# has no way to resolve the Vector back to the Velocity. I've hit this in the past before got it around by copy constructors.

So in your Vector class:

```
public class Vector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Copy Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="toCopy">
    /// The vector object to copy
    /// </param>
    public Vector(Vector toCopy)
    {
        if (toCopy == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("toCopy");
        }

        x = toCopy.x;
        y = toCopy.y;
        //What ever other properties you have, assign them here
    }
}
```

Then in your Velocity class:

```
public class Velocity : Vector
{
    public Velocity(Vector vector)
        : base(vector)
    {
    }
}
```

Finally, how this will be used:

```
Velocity result = new Velocity((v1).subtract(v2));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `Vector` class should accept a generic type parameter to let it know the type of its derived class:

```
public class Vector<TImpl> where TImpl : Vector
{
     public TImpl Subtract(TImpl v) 
     {
        double nx = this.x - v.x;
        double ny = this.y - v.y;
        double mag = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double ang = Math.Atan2(y, x);

        return (TImpl)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TImpl), new object[] { mag, ang });
    }
}

public class Velocity : Vector<Velocity>
{
}
```

BTW, I feel that `Subtract` method should be an *extension method* and everything will seem less odd:

```
public static class VectorExtensions
{
      public static TImpl Subtract<TImpl>(this TImpl vectorImpl, TImpl other)
             where TImpl : Vector
      {
        double nx = this.x - v.x;
        double ny = this.y - v.y;
        double mag = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double ang = Math.Atan2(y, x);

        return (TImpl)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TImpl), new object[] { mag, ang });
      }
}
```

...and you'll be able to reach your goal:

```
Velocity result = v1.Subtract(v2);
```

Comment: Using `(TImpl)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TImpl), new object[] { mag, ang })` looks ugly to me.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Give me an alternative and I'll improve the snippet :D

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen An alternative would be using an implicit interface implementation to being able to set some properties without making them public...

Comment: Not sure I understand. What interface with what properties (or methods)? _Explicit_ interface implementations are in a sense `public` (if the interface type is public; `internal` if the interface is that).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You know that explicit implementations are like *private* members in the class where they're implemented... Of course you can cast that implementation to the interface type to get access to its members.

Comment: In a sense they are private; it depends on what you mean. If I have a method `void IMyInterface.Method() { /* ... */ }`, then if it is "private", one could think that it meant I could call it from within the same class as just `Method();` or `this.Method();`, but this is not true. You could also think that it could _not_ be called from _outside_ the class if it is "private", but it can: `IMyInterface x = new TheClass(); x.Method();`. For this reason we should be careful to explain what we mean if we claim explicit interface implementations are "private". // Meanwhile, I still do not get it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It was just an idea I don't really like after all. If I would consider this approach a good one, it would be in the answer... The point is you can provide *setters* to set some data only if you cast a reference to a given explicitly implemented interface in order to avoid the constructor with parameters. BTW, again, I don't buy the idea, I was just thinking about alternatives to using `Activator`. I don't like the selected answer anyway...

Answer (score -1):

Please be advised that your code

```
Velocity result = (Velocity)v1.subtract(v2);
```

doesn't cast the result of subtract method to Velocity type. The correct way to do it is:

```
Velocity result = (Velocity)(v1.subtract(v2));
```

Comment: No. That would be the exact same thing and does not solve his/her issue.

Comment: This comment is incorrect. Something of the form `(T)v.s(u)` is already seen as `(T)(v.s(u))`, not as `((T)v).s(u)` as you seem to think. So the extra parenthesis is nice but not required, so your comment is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You don't habe to code three versions. 
You can Code a generic function.

```
public T Substract<T> (T vector) where T: Vector
{
    ...
    return new T(...); // Edited to demonstrate last line as asked from comment
}
```

Comment: That makes sense but how would that last line look? `return new T(mag, ang);`

Comment: It is a very nice answer.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I'm still doing something wrong.. This isn't right either `return T where T: Vector, new(mag, ang);`

Comment: I don't like this solution. Why you perform a subtraction against a `Velocity` and you need to provide the result type as generic parameter? It seems odd.

Comment: @ryanmattscott `new()` constraint is to define that `T` must provide a public parameterless constructor. There's no constraint to other kinds of constructors..

Comment: This answer is erroneous.  Again, there's no generic constraint to types with non-paramaterless constructors!

Comment: The line `return new T(...); // Edited to demonstrate last line as asked from comment` makes me downvote as well. `T` is defined by the method `Subtract<T>` itself, hence you cannot have new-object expression like that.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen right `return new T(...);` doesn't work. To make his idea work I did the following: http://pastebin.com/PPrQvDXT

Comment: @ryanmattscott OK, but `return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(T),
                new object[] { nx, ny });` is really ugly in my opinion.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Agreed I went with 
user2326106 suggestion instead. Seems to be the cleanest